# Why can I import python module's globals twice?

Tags: python, import

Please look at [this gist.](https://gist.github.com/phunc20/8eb8cb3d3fae14e08eb539c6dee1c8e1?fbclid=IwAR3Mgls1K1Q-lvZ3GOnS3i31GO4aMyk-lQm1c7QUmct5uCHv75f3YZYrfYE)

```
$ python main.py
var = 10
(main)       "var" in globals() = True
(change_var) "var" in globals() = True
sub1_globals == main_globals = False
var = 10
sub1_globals["var"] = 20
main_globals["var"] = 10
var is main_globals["var"] = True
var is sub1_globals["var"] = False
```

The `var` is changed by `change_var()`
But only affects the var in `sub1` module.

I want to change the `var` in the `main` module,
so I import the var again like this:
[import twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQYkm.jpg)

And then the var really changes!
How come?
Isn't python module can only be imported once?

Expected: The var is 10, not changed.

sub1.py

```
var = 10
def change_var():
    print(f'(change_var) {"var" in globals() = }')
    global var
    var = 20
    return globals()
```

main.py

```
from sub1 import var, change_var

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f'{var = }')
    print(f'(main)       {"var" in globals() = }')
    sub1_globals = change_var()
    main_globals = globals()
    print(f'{sub1_globals == main_globals = }')
    print(f'{var = }')
    print(f'{sub1_globals["var"] = }')
    print(f'{main_globals["var"] = }')
    print(f'{var is main_globals["var"] = }')
    print(f'{var is sub1_globals["var"] = }')
    from sub1 import var
    print(f"reimport {var = }")
```

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Edited. Thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you used `import` to get the initial value of `var`, there's no connection between the `var` in your module and the `var` in your main.  They're completely independent, disconnected.  So when you change the one in your module, it doesn't affect the one in main even though they have the same name.

But when you import it a second time, you're saying you want the current value, which you've changed.  It's no different than saying `var = 20`, you told Python explicitly that you wanted a new value for `var`.

Comment: So that means I can import the var again even though it was imported once before?
How come? Isn't the module listed in `sys.modules`?

Comment: @Drunkwcodes yes, the module is cached in `sys.modules` and you will only ever have one copy.  But that doesn't mean the module isn't free to change its contents.

Answer (score 0):

if you transfer global var and var = 10 to main.py, you will see that the key is in the *. if you import * you will force python to review everything and since you are changing var globaly in the stack, the variable changes. but if you import only the module change_var, your variable will stay unchanged. So yes, modules in python can only be imported once, but you are importing * not modules.

Comment: I use `from sub1 import var` also successfully change it to 20.